# Copying formatted string causes a perfect crash

Tags: bugs, front-end, crash

**Bug introduced in 10.1 or earlier and persisting through 11.1**

---

Consider the string generated by this line:

```
EllipticTheta::usage // FullForm
```

Highlight everything except the leading and trailing quotations as shown:

[image: a]

Attempt to copy highlighted text using <kbd>⌘+C</kbd> on a Mac.

On my computer (Mac OS X 10.11, *Mathematica* 10.3, 10.4, 11.0), *Mathematica* vanishes-- the front end and the kernel is killed by the OS.

Would someone confirm this behavior?  If this is a crash due to Mathematica and not my machine, I will report.

---

**update**

I've narrowed the pathological behavior to the part that contains `\"u` or `\"q` in the usage.  I observe that any selection that contains this string as a subset will cause *Mathematica* to crash:

[image]

Can anyone verify this?

Comment: Works perfectly fine on my machine (both Mathematica 10.4 and 11 on OS X 10.11.6)

Comment: @Sascha Oh, I'm on OS X 10.11.5.  Let me update to 10.11.6 and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Sascha Nope; still crashes for me.

Comment: Works fine for me on Debian Stable, both select-middle:mouse and ctrl+c:ctrl+v

Comment: This crashes V11 on OSX 10.10.6 as well

Comment: confirmed crash behavior on: SystemInformationData[{"Kernel" -> {"Version" -> 
     "11.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)", 
    "ReleaseID" -> "11.0.0.0 (5570718, 2016072801)", 
    , "PatchLevel" -> "0",
MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012)
OS X 10.11.6 (15G31)

Comment: I can confirm that the string `\"u` is sufficient to trigger this on my system (V11.0.0 under Linux Mint 17.3).  In other contexts, this string is not sufficient so there is obviously some context dependency.

Comment: I confirm the crash with versions 11.0.0 and 10.4.1 on Win7 x64: an attempt to copy the `\"q` causes immediate crash! With version 8.0.4 there is no crash.

Comment: Confirmed on 11.0.0 Windows 8.1 x64. Nice find. Debugger reveals "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF6EA4A0105 in Mathematica.exe: 0xC000041D: movzx       eax,word ptr [r8+rax*2]  "

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried this in V11.0.0 and V10.4 on Linux  (<kbd>control-c</kbd> to copy).  In the terminal from which I launched Mathematica I see:

> Mathematica has received the signal: SIGSEGV and has exited. If
>   possible, please report this problem to support@wolfram.com describing
>   in as much detail as possible what you were doing when the problem
>   occurred.

Comment: What linux distribution are you using?

Comment: Linux mint 17.3 (from memory)